# Laravel HTML Form strange issue

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I have very strange situation with Larave 5.2.45 and laravelcollective/html 5.2.*
I have two different sites on my computer, using the same form just with some small changes.

I have an array with field names. For each of them I am generating an dropdown menu like this:

```
{!! Form::select($field.'[]', $values, $selected_values, ['class' => 'ui fluid dropdown', 'multiple']) !!}
```

On website 1 that works fine, on website 2 it does not work. It generates me an error:

```
ErrorException in Model.php line 2723: Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation (View:
```

If I change the code to:

```
{!! Form::select($field.'_[]', $values, $selected_values, ['class' => 'ui fluid dropdown', 'multiple']) !!}
```

it works than fine. Just adding one "_" to the name of the field. Any ideas why is that ?

Thanks in advance !